# Time UTC stamp displaying wrong Date threw PHP date function

Tags: php

I am using this below function for utc timestamp to date conversation but its giving me wrong  answer.

```
echo  date('Y-m-d H:i:s',1379658966473);
```

Its give me in returns

```
45689-08-26 01:47:53
```

But actually answer is

```
GMT: Fri, 20 Sep 2013 06:36:06 GMT
Your time zone: 20 September 2013 12:06:06 PM GMT+5.5
```

which i got from http://www.epochconverter.com/ online converter website which is doing right

Comment: It seems you give `microtime` instead of `time` to date function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timestamp is in a miliseconds format. To get regular unix timestamp, divide it by 1000:

```
$timestamp = 1379658966473 / 1000;
echo  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for reference, the answer is there too.

Answer (score 1):

your timestamp is for microtime, date function require a simple timestamp, you need to use time() function instead of microtime()